# Having trouble with Inverse Laplace Transform involving a series

Tags: laplace-transform

So I have $$\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}=\frac{1-e^{-3s}}{s(1+e^{-3s})}$$

$f(t)$ is the function whose laplace transform is above. Suppose Y(s) is the Laplace transform of the solution to the Initial Value Problem $$y'(t) = 10f(t) \quad \text{with} \quad y(0)=0$$

Find an expression for Y(s):

I got $$sY(s) - 0 = \frac{10(1-e^{-3s})}{s(1+e^{-3s})}$$ so $$Y(s) = \frac{10(1-e^{-3s})}{s^2(1+e^{-3s})}$$

Now, by writing $\frac{1-e^{-3s}}{1+e^{-3s}}$ as the infinite series $$\frac{1-e^{-3s}}{1+e^{-3s}} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j(e^{-3js} -e^{-3(j+1)s})$$

Find the solution to the Initial Value Problem above.

I know this is probably really simple, and I know how to integrate series etc, but I am struggling to see how I approach this.

Do I multiply the $\frac{10}{s^2}$ through the series and then integrate term by term using the Heaviside function result?

Hints preferred, although if suggesting one approach over another, a short explanation of why (in case it isn't obvious) please.

Comment: $\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{10 (1-\exp (-3 s))}{s^2 (1+\exp (-3 s))}\right](t)=15 \text{TriangleWave}\left[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{t}{6}\right]$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notation: $\overline{f} = \overline{f}(s)$ is the transformed function and $f(t) \doteqdot f(s)$ shows the function and its transform.

Consider $y^{'}(t) = a \, f(t)$ the then Laplace transform is
$$ s \, \overline{y} - y_{0} = a \, \overline{f} $$
with
$$ f \doteqdot \frac{1 - e^{-b s}}{s \, (1 + e^{- b s})}. $$
Now, by using
$$ \begin{cases} 0 & 0 < t < a \\ t - a & a < t < b \\ b-a & t > b \end{cases}  \, =  (t-a) \, H(t-a) + (b-t) \, H(t-b) \doteqdot \frac{e^{-a s} - e^{-b s}}{s^2}, $$
where $H(t)$ is the Heaviside step function, and
\begin{align}
f(t) &\doteqdot \frac{1 - e^{-b s}}{s \, (1 + e^{- b s})} \\
&\doteqdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \, \frac{e^{- b k s} - e^{- b (k+1) s}}{s}
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
\overline{y} &\doteqdot \frac{y_{0}}{s} + \frac{a \, \overline{f}}{s} \\
&\doteqdot \frac{y_{0}}{s} + a \, \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \, \frac{e^{- b k s} - e^{- b (k+1) s}}{s^2} \\
y(t) &= y_{0} + a \, \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \, \left[ (t-b k) \, H(t-b k) + (b(k+1)-t) \, H(t-b(k+1)) \right].
\end{align}

It may be possible to give a solution in terms of error functions, but the one presented here could be efficient enough to obtain properties and compute the series further.